# SIGNALR: The written text is displayed to other users during writing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am developing a MVC Web application with SIGNALR. But I get strange behavior, in practice if two or more users are connected the text that a user writes is instantly replicated in "realtime" to other users without pressing the SEND key. The text is inserted and replicated into a textarea.

For the rest everything works properly.

Someone to some idea what it might be or has already happened.

Thank you so much for your support.

Francesco.

Comment: Could you share the code? We need to see what you have in order to identify the bug.

Comment: There is no way anyone can effectively help you with this little information.

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: you want realtime replication on typing or not dont want?

Comment: you're probably handling the textarea keydown/keyup event or using some js framework that does that for you, and in that handler you're doing the sync using signalr